# Delete Pointer to PFObject in parse?

Tags: ios, parse-platform

I have a PFObject "A", one of the fields in A is a pointer to PFObject "B".

So, if I delete B, A still keeps the old pointer to B.

How can I clear out the pointer to PFObject B found in PFObject A?

Comment: "When I try to delete the pointer in A...", which code are you using? `aPFObject.bPFObject` = nil; ?

Comment: @gothicdev: I edited the question shortly after I posted it. I think I wasn't too clear about it. I am deleting B, so now I want to delete the pointer that A still has to B. It does not go away by deleting B. Not sure I am understanding how to handle this scenario.

Comment: You need to get A and use 'removeObjectForKey' to remove pointer to B.

Comment: @knshn: if you make this an answer I'll mark it as the right one. It works.

Answer (score 1):

If you delete B, it doesn't delete the pointer from A to B. So, first you need to get A, and then use `removeObjectForKey` to remove the pointer.